# Convolution of an $L^p$ function with a Compactly supported continuous function. What does it give?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, convolution

CLARIFICATION : In the following discussion $g \in C_c(\Bbb R^n)$ is always assumed to be non-zero.

> I know that if for $1 ≤ p ≤ 2$ take a $f ∈ L^ p (\Bbb R^n )$, and  a $g ∈ C_ c (\Bbb R^n )$ such that $f ∗ g ≡ 0$ it is true that $f(x) = 0$, for almost every $x ∈ \Bbb R^n$ .

I have proved this using the facts that the fourier transform of $g$ can be seen as restriction of an entire function on $\Bbb R$ and then   $f ∗ g ≡ 0 \implies \hat{(f*g)}=0 \implies \hat f . \hat g=0$ would imply from Uniqueness principle that  $\hat f$ must vanish except at most on a set of measure zero, then injectivity of fourier transform yields that $f =0$ a.e.

My question is

> What can be said  if we replace the above range of $p$ to be $(2,\infty]$ ?

Since $L^\infty$ is such a troublesome space to work with in Fourier Analysis, I'd want to treat it in a separate case.

So my questions are :

> $(\mathscr{Q.1})$ If $f \in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ for some $2< p<\infty$ and $g \in C_c(\Bbb R^n)$ and we have $f*g \equiv 0 $ , then can we say anything analogous to the case when $1 \le p \le 2$ ?

For $2 < p < \infty$ , I am unable justify the steps $\hat{(f*g)}=0 \implies \hat f . \hat g=0$ and after all, here we are dealing with tempered distributions, so can somehow we use its support ?

> $(\mathscr{Q.2})$ If $f \in L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ and $g \in C_c(\Bbb R^n)$ and we have $f*g \equiv 0 $ , then can we say anything analogous to the case when $1 \le p \le 2$ ?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Can I argue along the same lines?

Comment: @CameronWilliams $C_c \subset L^1$ , now apply Young's inequality to see that $f \in L^p \implies f*g \in L^p$

Comment: Fair fair @Brozovic. I was imagining a "pointwise" understanding. Deleted my comment as such.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro So for $L^\infty$ case it's not true since we can just take $f \equiv 1$ and $g \in C_c$ such that $\int_{\Bbb R^n} g=0$ , right?

Comment: Didn't say exactly that; I merely said that your Fourier transform proof breaks down. But, yes, you can directly check that what you have is a counterexample. Indeed, $1\ast g(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} g(y)\, dy=0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yeah! But how to proceed for $2 < p < \infty$ ?

Comment: The answer of Jose27 uncovered an interesting connection between this problem and the problem of the [restriction of the Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Restriction_problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submit a solution to the remaining open question, which I repeat here to ease reading.

> **Question (Q2)**. Let $2<p<\infty$. Are there $0\ne f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $0\ne g\in C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ such that  $f\ast g=0$?
>
> **Answer**.
> They exist if and only if $p>\frac{2n}{n-1}$.

*Proof* (SKETCH - INCOMPLETE). The "if" part has been cleverly solved by Jose27. We turn to the "only if". The equation $f\ast g=0$ is equivalent to $\hat{f}\hat{g}=0$, and $\hat{g}$ is analytic. Thus, there is a solution if and only if there is $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\hat{f}$ is supported on the zero set of $\hat{g}$.

We assume that the zero set of $\hat{g}$ is the unit sphere. This means that $\hat{f}$ is supported on the unit sphere, hence that it is of the form $\hat{f}=F\, d\sigma$, where $d\sigma$ denotes the surface measure. Now, the principle of stationary phase implies that
$$
f(x)=\int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} F(\xi)e^{ix\cdot \xi}\, d\sigma(\xi) \sim \frac{C}{\lvert x \rvert^{\frac{n-1}{2}}},\quad |x|\to \infty, $$
where $\sim$ means "asymptotically equivalent" (i.e., the ratio tends to 1). And so, if $A>0$ is sufficiently big,
$$
\int_{|x|>A}|f(x)|^p\, dx \ge C\int_{|x|>A} |x|^{-p\frac{n-1}{2}}\, dx, $$
which is infinite if $p\le \frac{2n}{n-1}$.

**TO DO**.

1. Explain why it is sufficient to assume that $\hat{g}=0$ is the sphere. The hand-waving reason is that the zero set must have nonvanishing Gaussian curvature, otherwise $f$ would not decay in one direction and thus fail to be in $L^p$. Once there is nonvanishing Gaussian curvature, we can assume that the surface is either the sphere or the paraboloid, all the others are essentially the same as those two.
2. Fill in the details of the principle of stationary phase.

---

**PREVIOUS VERSION OF THIS POST**. What follows is obsolete.

**Connection with Stein-Tomas extension estimate**.

Jose27 unveiled the connection between Q2 and the *restriction/extension problem* of harmonic analysis.$^{[1]}$  For the case of the sphere, Tomas and Stein proved the following *extension inequality*
$$
\lVert \widehat{F\, d\sigma}\rVert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R^n)}\le C\lVert F\rVert_{L^2(d\sigma)}, $$
where $C>0$, $\sigma$ denotes the surface measure on the sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$, and $$p\ge p_0:=2(n+1)/(n-1).$$ This is related with Q2, because as Jose27 points out, we can take
$$
f=\widehat{F\, d\sigma}, $$
(in Jose's post, $F=1$). We thus get $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, and now we can construct $g\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\hat{g}$ vanishes on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ using [the Schwartz-Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz%27s_Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem). Therefore, $f\ast g$ has a vanishing Fourier transform; that is, $f\ast g=0$.

**This implies that the answer to Q2 is negative for $p\ge p_0$**.

Can we go below $p_0$? For that, we should find a function $F\in L^2(d\sigma)$ such that $\widehat{Fd\sigma}\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ for some $p<p_0$.

> The measure $d\sigma$ needs not be the surface measure on the sphere; other surfaces, perhaps of higher codimension, or even curves, should do. Can someone check? The book on harmonic analyis of Stein is the obvious place to start.

---

[1] "Restriction" and "extension" refer to estimates which are dual to each other. Thus, one can formulate the problem in terms of one or another, but the content is essentially the same. Here, we need the "extension" estimate, but the problem is more often known as "restriction".

Comment: @DavidCUllrich: I would really like to know your opinion on this problem, if you visit this post. Thanks!

Comment: Just a bit of nitpicking. Your $p_0$ and mine are different; in fact in the context of the restriction problem my $p_0=2n/(n-1)$ is the expected range for which we should have restriction estimates. OTOH $p_0=2(n+1)/(n-1)$ is the exponent that Stein-Thomas gives, using decay properties of $\hat{\sigma}$.

Comment: @Jose27: thank you, I am learning a lot from this discussion. The "nitpicking" you mentioned is explained [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/restriction-conjecture/). This is not nitpicking at all, of course. For this problem, the critical exponent is $2n/(n-1)$, not $2(n+1)/(n-1)$, as you clearly show with your answer. I have a question which may possibly be trivial. What happens if, instead of the spherical measure $d\sigma$, you take $ds$, the arclength of a $1$-d circle sitting in $\mathbb R^n$? How does $\widehat{ds}$ decay? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No problem, I'm also learning a lot! If yo have a circle sitting on hyperplane I would expect the Fourier transform to not decay at all (in the direction normal to said plane). What I was wondering is that maybe the opposite happens: As p gets closer to $2n/(n-1)$, the support of the FT of an $L^p$ function should be at least $2n/q$ dimensional (here q is the Hölder conjugate to $p$). This would settle the problem (at least for $p>2n/(n-1)$) since analytic functions can only have $n-1$-dimensional zero sets.

Comment: Of course I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: You are completely right. Great. Analytic functions can only have $n-1$ dimensional zero sets; for our purposes these sets need have nonvanishing Gaussian curvature. Thus, there are only two possibilities; either the sphere or the paraboloid. I have a question for you: can it be that the paraboloid yields a lower $p$? Thanks!

Comment: @Jose27:  I think that the paraboloid is no use whatsoever, for the only extension estimate it has is the Tomas-Stein one; $$\lVert e^{it\Delta} f\rVert_{L^{2+\frac{4}{n-1}}(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R^{n-1})}\le C\lVert f \rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R^{n-1})},$$ which is usually called "Strichartz estimate". Your conjecture is really plausible.

Comment: Very nice! I'm not completely sold on one point of the reduction though: the fact that $\hat{f} $ is supported inside of the sphere doesn't preclude it from being lower dimensional (in fact even if the support is the whole sphere I'm wary that the measure we get $\mu=\hat{f} $ could happen that $\mu$ has nontrivial singular part with respect to surface measure). I'm not too sure, but I think justifying this might boil down to a variant of my conjecture. I'll have to think more about this though.

Comment: @Jose27: I am absolutely not sure, but I think that, if there is a singular part, [then the Fourier transform does not vanish at infinity](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24890717?seq=1); Theorem 2.7. This would contradict $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$. If the support is lower dimensional, I intuitively expect that we would not get better decay than $\lvert x \rvert^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}$ at $|x|\to \infty$, but this should be proved. The answer might lie in [this aforementioned MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/242862/13042), or from a careful stationary phase computation (which I skipped here ...)

Answer (score 5):

**WARNING**. This answer is correct only in dimension $n=1$.

---

The answer to Q2 (the $p=\infty$ case) is negative; a counterexample is $f=1$ and $g$ such that $\hat{g}(0)=0$. Indeed,
$$
1\ast g(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} g(y)\, dy=\hat{g}(0)=0.$$

The answer to Q1 is affirmative.

> **EDIT**. I just found a mistake. The following is correct only for $n=1$. I still think that the result is true in generality, but it needs some more work.

If $f\ast g=0$, then $\hat{f}\hat{g}=0$; note that this last product makes sense, as $\hat{g}$ is a smooth function, and actually it is analytic, while $\hat{f}$ is a tempered distribution.

> Now, $\hat{g}$ only has isolated zeros, by analyticity; denote them by $z_1, z_2, \ldots$.

**EDIT**. The above needs not be true for $n>1$. For example, the compactly supported function $g(x)=\prod_{j=1}^n \mathbf 1_{[-1, 1]}(x_j)$ has the Fourier transform
$$
\hat{g}(\xi)=\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{\sin \xi_j}{\xi_j}, $$
which is analytic and which has non-isolated zeros. **END EDIT**.

Thus, $\hat{f}\hat{g}=0$ implies that $\hat{f}$ is a distribution supported in $\{z_1, z_2, \ldots\}$, and the only such distributions have the form
$$
\hat{f}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{m\in N(j)} a_{mj} \partial^m \delta_{z_j}, $$
where $N(j)$ is a finite set of multi-indices, and $a_{mj}\in \mathbb C$. $^{[1]}$

Therefore, inverting the Fourier transform, we see that
$$
f=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{m\in N(j)} a_{mj} i^{|m|} e^{i x\cdot z_j} x^m, $$
which is a contradiction with the assumption $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, with $p<\infty$.

---

$^{[1]}$ A *multi-index* $m$ is a $n$-uple $(m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_n)\in\mathbb N^n$. We denote $\partial^m:=\partial_{x_1}^{m_1}\ldots \partial_{x_n}^{m_n}$ and $x^m :=x_1^{m_1}\ldots x_n^{m_n}$ and $\lvert m\rvert:= m_1+\ldots + m_n$. This is a standard terminology of distribution theory.

Comment: So that expression regarding $\hat{f}$ , it seems like you are trying to write in terms of 'basis'. Can you please elaborate on this about the 'basis' stuff on the space of temepered distributions? I have no knowledge , whatsoever regarding this!

Comment: No, no basis at all. I am using this result: the only distributions supported at a single point $x$ are the linear combinations $\sum_{m} a_m\partial^m \delta_x$, where $m=(m_1\ldots m_n)$ is a multi-index. The anti-Fourier transform of such a linear combination is $\sum_m a_m (i x)^m, $ where $x^m$ means $x_1^{m_1} x_2^{m_2}\ldots x_n^{m_n}$.

Answer (score 3):

The result is not true for $n\geq 2$, at least not in the full range: Let $p_0=2n/(n-1)$, then for every $p>p_0$ there exists $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $g\neq 0 \neq f$ and $f*g=0$.

We'll take $f= \check{\sigma}$, where $\sigma= \mathcal{H}^{n-1}|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ is the surface measure on the sphere. It's known (see for example Grafakos's book "Modern Fourier Analysis", it's an appendix if I recall correctly) 
$$
|f(x)|\lesssim (1+|x|)^{-(n-1)/2}.
$$
Therefore $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for every $p>p_0$.

Now consider the function $H:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ given by 
$$
H(z)=e^{i(z_1+\ldots + z_n)}(z_1^2+\ldots +z_n^2-1),
$$
where $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$. Then $H$ is entire and 
$$
|H(z)|\leq (1+|z|)^2 e^{|\text{Im}(z)|},
$$
so that by a Paley-Wiener Theorem (see Strichartz's book on distributions, or the Wikipedia page) $H=\hat{h}$ for a compactly supported distribution $h$. Now take $g=h*\eta$ for some $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to obtain that $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\hat{g}= H \hat{\eta}$, which vanishes on the unit sphere.

Note that for $n=1$ we have no decay since the measure $\sigma$ is just a sum of Dirac masses. This agrees with @GiuseppeNegro's result that $p=\infty$ is the only failure there. On the other hand for $p>2$ and $n\geq 2$ Fourier transforms of $L^p$ functions may be supported on lower dimensional sets. I'm not sure that $p_0$ is sharp though, so one question remains:

Is the original question true for $p\in (2,2n/(n-1)]$?

Comment: Great. I would say that any $f$ such that $\hat{f}$ is supported on a $n-1$ dimensional compact manifold should have the same decay properties of $\check{\sigma}$. So, to obtain new counterexamples and possibly lower the range of $p$, we should look for: 1) non-compact (n-1)-dimensional manifolds, or 2) compact (n-2)-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: [This note](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Kriventsov.pdf) quickly explains the decay property of $\check{\sigma}$.

Comment: And [this MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/242862/13042) is closely related. It describes the decay of the Fourier transforms of higher codimension manifolds.

Comment: Couldn't you just define $H(z_1\ldots z_n):=\sum |z_j|^2-1$? Why the exponential factor? Thanks!

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: $|z|^2$ is not analytic, the other factor is just to have it look exactly as in the Paley-Wiener Theorem.

Comment: I think that taking $H(z_1, \ldots, z_n):=z_1^2+z_2^2+\ldots+z_n^2-1$ is enough to apply [Schwartz-Paley-Wiener's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz's_Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem). Anyway, that's not the important point. Your answer shows the connection with the restriction estimate of Stein-Tomas (see the note from my previous comment, or [the lecture notes of Tao](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254b.1.99s/)). In particular, by the result of Stein, the answer to the present question is negative for $p=\frac{2n}{n-1}$.